# How do you submit an API request from the front-end based on the result of a previous API request on an Apollo graphql server?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-mutation

I'm working with two API endpoints.  The first one returns a list of dates in a string format for which data is available.  The date can then be added to the second endpoint and renders additional data. On the Graphql Playground I have been able to make it all work.  On the front-end I have a select option drop down for the dates, but I have not been able to fire off the second API call when I click on any given date.  It's the first time I'm using graphql mutation and I haven't been able to get the second API request to return any data when I select a date.  Thank you.

Front-end code:

***app.tsx***

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { IrriSatQuery } from '../../generated/graphql'
import { MAP_LAYER } from './query'

interface Props {
  data: IrriSatQuery;
}

const IrriSat: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState((data?.mapDates as any)[0].date!)
  const [getLayer] = useMutation(MAP_LAYER)

  return (
    <>

    <ContentWrapper>
      <select value={option} onChange={( e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>, ): void => {setOption(e.target.value, getLayer(e.target.value)}} onSelect={() => getLayer({variables: {type: option}})}>
        {data?.mapDates?.slice(0,52).map(res => 
          <option key={res?.date!} value={res?.date!}>{res?.date}</option>
          )
        }
      </select>
    </ContentWrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default IrriSat
```

***query.ts***

```
export const QUERY_IRR_SAT = gql`
 query IrriSat {
   mapDates {
     date
     dateurl
   }
 }
`

export const MAP_LAYER = gql`
  mutation MapLayer($date: String!) {
     mapDate(date: $date) {
       token
       mapid
       name
     }

   }
`
```

Back-end code:

**server.js**

```
class IrriSatAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = 'https://irrisat-cloud.appspot.com/_ah/api/irrisat/v1/services/'
  }

  async getMapsDates() {
    const response = await this.get('maps/dates')
    return Array.isArray(response.items) ? response.items.map(response => this.mapsDatesReducer(response)) : []
  }

  mapsDatesReducer(response) {
    return {
      date: response.date,
      dateurl: response.dateurl,
    }
  }

  async getMapsLayer(date) {

    const response = await this.get(`maps/layers/${date}`)
    return Array.isArray(response.items) ? response.items.map(response => this.mapsLayerReducer(response)) : []
  }

  mapsLayerReducer(response) {
    return {
      token: response.token,
      mapid: response.mapid,
      name: response.name
    }
  }


  }
}
```

**schema.js**

```
  type MapDates {
    date: String
    dateurl: String
  }

  type Mutation {
    mapDate(date: String): [MapsLayers]
  }

  type Query {
    mapDates: [MapDates]
```

**resolver.js**

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    mapDates: (_, __, { dataSources }) => dataSources.irriSatAPI.getMapsDates(),
  },
  Mutation: {
    mapDate: (_, { date }, { dataSources }) => dataSources.irriSatAPI.getMapsLayer(date)
  }
}
```

Comment: not fired at all? render links/buttons in a loop (to learn how to use variables) - check dev tools/network (to check if request fired) ..... no mutation result data used (you can use 'onCompleted' handler option of mutation - with another setState - why overwriting data from props? use some 'selectedDate'?) ... you can use `useEffect` to call **normal query** (not mutation) on `option` change (effect dependency, effect fired at start and forced by `setOption`) because you're not changing remote data ... rethink your data state and flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your `onChange` function.

You are calling getLayer twice? You should only need to call it once, at the same time as you set the value of the dropdown. Also, as far as I know, you don't really need the `onSelect`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const MAP_LAYER = gql`
    mutation MapLayer($date: String!) {
        mapDate(date: $date) {
            token
            mapid
            name
        }
    }
`;

const ContentWrapper = ({ children }) => <div>{...children}</div>;

const IrriSat: React.FC<any> = ({ data }) => {
    const [option, setOption] = useState((data?.mapDates as any)[0].date!);
    const [getLayer]: any = useMutation(MAP_LAYER);

    return (
        <ContentWrapper>
            <select
                value={option}
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
                    setOption(e.target.value);
                    getLayer({ variables: { date: e.target.value } });
                }}
            >
                {data?.mapDates?.slice(0, 52).map(res => (
                    <option key={res?.date!} value={res?.date!}>
                        {res?.date}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </ContentWrapper>
    );
};

export default IrriSat;
```

Obviously, I changed a few things to get rid of some of the editor warnings, but pay particular attention to the onChange property.

A tip: you are probably experiencing these issues due to the *extreme* length of the line that you add all of this logic condensed into. Install the "Prettier - Code formatter" VS Code extension. Enable VS Code's format on save option. Profit.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to remove the onSelect when I posed the question.  I didn't mean to call getLayer twice.  Anyway, they key so far was to set the getLayer variable to "date".  I now get the data in GraphiQL in DevTools.  I still need to figure out how to actually access the data.  Really appreciate your help.